# Does NodeJS recluster module maintains sticky session

Tags: node.js, npm, sticky

I am using Nodejs npm [recluster](http://www.npmjs.com/package/recluster), I just want to know that do recluster maintains sticky session or not i.e for example if user 1's first request went to the first worker then whether recluster ensures that the next subsequent requests will also go to the same first worker?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of recluster, I'd say that it does not. It's just a wrapper around node.js core cluster module, which will handle its own load balancing. Ultimately you're application should be completely stateless. You're design shouldn't need sticky sessions, unless its unavoidable or difficult to avoid.

If you're using webSockets this won't matter, a socket is persistent with that host. If you're using socket.io then you'll have a problem with long-polling fallback, but regardless even if you use sockets you should still always provide session data. HTTP is stateless in its own, so trying to manage state by persisting session through sticky session is never going to work well. You should still manage your own sessions, and in doing so you won't have to worry about session affinity(sticky sessions).